# Почему смещение 0x3C в PE указывает на 1 байт а не 4?

Tags: exe, hex, dos, pe

Разбираюсь с устройством PE, из википедии вычитал что по смещению 0x3C находится dword который указывает на PE header:

[Первые 2 байта PE-файла содержат сигнатуру 0x4D 0x5A — «MZ» (как наследник MZ-формата). Далее — двойное слово по смещению 0x3C содержит адрес PE-заголовка. Последний начинается с сигнатуры 0x50 0x45 — «PE».](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)

Но по этому смещению лежит 1 байт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя должно же 00 00 00 F0

Comment: x86 — [архитектура остроконечников](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)!

Comment: Большинство PE-файлов использует little endian, значит должно быть именно F0 00 00 00